# I cant figure out where to put a loop

Tags: java

I have tried a `do` loop and a `while` loop. I just can't seem to figure out where to put a loop so once the program has completely run I want it to Question the user "Yes I want to continue" or "No" and it ends.  This is a class assignment and I am using eclipse and it correct somethings which really sent me for a loop myself.

Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class studentgpa {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner consoleInput = extracted();
        printGPA(consoleInput);     
    }
    public static void printGPA(Scanner input) {
        System.out.println("Enter a student record: ");
        String name = extracted().next();
        System.out.print("Enter Number of grades you will be entering: ");
        int count = extracted().nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        System.out.println("Enter Grades: 95 enter 98 enter and so on ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            sum += extracted().nextInt();
        }
        double average = (double) sum / count;

        System.out.println(name + "'s grade is " + average);
    }
    private static Scanner extracted() {
        return new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the loop for? For many students?

Comment: yes Its to add several students  say like Mathew do the grades then sam and so on.

Comment: Add the `while` loop in your `main` method and call `printGPA` based on `Yes` or `No`. :)

Comment: i guess its time to accept one these answers

Answer (score 1):

You would need to wrap the content inside of main in a do while loop like this and prompt the user asking if they want to continue

```
do {
    Scanner consoleInput = extracted();
    printGPA(consoleInput);
    System.out.println("Do you want to add another student? (Yes/No)");
    String continue = consoleInput.nextLine(); // storing the user's response
} while (continue.equals("Yes"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just begin your function printGPA with a String like this

```
String continueLoop="Yes";
while("Yes".equals(continueLoop)){
 ///put the code you already have
 continueLoop=extracted().next();
}
```

The code above will loop until you enter something other than "Yes".

Comment: @AbishekManoharan Haha, sorry i've been using a lot of goto's lately :). I will correct my answer

Comment: I have tried to and Witht he changes from Eclipse adding all the extracted and some other lines I kinda got lost.

Comment: @Unholy what kind of changes?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to ask the user then you need to add a `loop` at the `begining` of `printGPA`.

```
String ans="yes";
while(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){//checks  the user input is yes or no
      //your code
      System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
      ans=extracted().next();
 }
```

After changes, the pringtGPA should look like this

```
public static void printGPA(Scanner input)
{
        String ans="yes";
        while(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")){
            System.out.println("Enter a student record: ");
            String name = extracted().next();
            System.out.print("Enter Number of grades you will be entering: ");
            int count = extracted().nextInt();
            int sum = 0;
            System.out.println("Enter Grades: 95 enter 98 enter and so on ");
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
                sum += extracted().nextInt();
            }
           double average = (double) sum / count;

           System.out.println(name + "'s grade is " + average);

           System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
           ans=extracted().next();
        }//end of while loop
}
```

Hope it helps.Happy Coding!!